# Python - Regular Expression

Tags: python

Which string is there.

```
"100-200*300-500+20"
```

The general operation sequence is as follows.

- "*" > "+" == "-"

  "(((100-(200*300))-500)+20)" ==> -60380

But I want to change the order of operation.

For Example)

- "*" > "+" > "-"

  "(100-(200*300))-**(500+20)**" == > -60420

Therefore, I used regular expression.

sg = '*' or '+' or '-'

`p = re.search(r'[-]?[\d]+[{0}][-]?[\d]+'.format(sg), "100-200*300-500+20")`

But it doesn't give the result I want.

The result I want is this.

`"100-(200*300)-500+20" ==> 100-60000-(500+20) ==> (100-60000)-520 ==> (-59900-520) ==> -60420`

But it works like this.

`"100(-200*300)-500+20" ==> 100-60000(-500+20) ==> (100-60000)-480 ==> (-59900-480) ==> -60380`

The number given as input does not have a negative number.

For example)

- 100-(500+20) : True
- 100(-500+20) : False

However, the calculated result can be negative.

For example)

- 100-60000-300 ==> -59900-300 ==> -60200 : True
- 100-60000-300 ==> -(59900-300) ==> -59600 : False

**I want the correct regular expression.**

Comment: If the input never has negative numbers, then simply get rid of both `[-]?` in the regex.

Comment: But when that happens, the "-" is not recognized in the calculated expression.